# Wordpress Two Step Login

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I would like wp login form to have two steps authentication.

1.) If the username exists, **¹** password field appears.
2.) If the username doesn't exist, the password field is hidden.

¹ visitor must type correct username to proceed to step two.*

Where can I begin my quest to have the login form "detect usernames" in the DB?
If there is a better way, may you please share your idea?

Thanks for your attention,

Comment: This is not recommended, it makes hacker life easy. You are solving half of their problem, with such login they can easily know which username is present in db and then only need to guess the password.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has the [function username_exists](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/username_exists). You should start there.

As for 'If there's a better way...'; I don't know what you want to achieve. It's looks like a lot of work for something that adds very little to the user experience and could cause security issues like Maggew said.